# Neo4j query to get a document with no parent

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relation in neo4j

```
(d:Document)-[r:HAS_PARENT]->(p:Document)
```

but sometime my document have parents.

I want to fetch documents who are not linked with other document by the HAS_PARENT relation ship

How can I do ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a simple `WHERE` clause:

```
MATCH (d:Document)
WHERE NOT (d)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(:Document)
RETURN d
```